# How "threads" get CPU and time slice?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, architecture, linux-kernel

Kindly, help me understand the following 'thread' concepts:

1. If concurrently running threads are part of a running process, how is time slice divided between multiple threads of a same process?
2. Also, since there is no new Process Control Clock created, how do they get their share of CPU allocation? Is it like, dispatcher lets TCB access CPU?

Answer (score 1):

That's operating system [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Types_of_operating_system_schedulers) job. The OS has a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) of active threads, it implements scheduling algorithm to make sure each thread is given amount of CPU time to run. For example Linux uses [Completely Fair Scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler)